# Automatic SVN conflict handling for XML files

Tags: xml, svn, tortoisesvn, merge-conflict-resolution

I would like to make conflict resolutions automatic. My project uses XML files to save data and users do not have knowledge about SVN or XML editing. They use TortoiseSVN to commit and update their work with other users. To resolve the conflicts, I would like to insert the 'mine' block after 'theirs' block.
The blocks have same numbers of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically in your scenario, no, it's not possible. You can either have SVN automatically use your version of the file, or the version someone else committed to the repository - but not both.

You'd need to run:

> svn merge SOURCE[@REV] [TARGET_WCPATH] --accept mine-full

if you want Subversion to auto-resolve conflicts using your version of the file, or

> svn merge SOURCE[@REV] [TARGET_WCPATH] --accept theirs-full

if you want Subversion to auto-resolve conflicts using the repository's version of the file.

Unfortunately, there is no in-between.

Comment: The other tools for that purpose, like Mercurial or Git, offer the solution to my problem?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, but I don't think _any_ VCS would have that sort of capability - it seems too dangerous to automate something like that. Git does have a relatively better merging algorithm, so the occurrences of conflicts should happen less often, but whether it auto-merges files the way you'd want is anyone's guess. Sorry!